Cannot acces external disk
I connect my external disk and what appears is "THIS LOCATION COULD NOT BE DISPLAYED", sorry could not display all the contents of "Seagate basic": error when getting information for file "..........." input/output error.
Yesterday I solved a problem in the same disk using:
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Thanks in advance.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. This sounds like a standard read error. It could be caused by a number of things. If the device is a USB-powered spinning disk, it might not be getting enough power to complete the initialisation. If it’s an SSD, there could be an issue with the read descriptor, which happens due to excessive wear.  Either way, there is an insufficient amount of information to know for certain.

This is most likely a hardware error. Try to check the drive with smartmontools. Example: sudo smartctl -H /dev/nvme0n1

Thanks for the reply. Tried sudo smartctl -H /dev/nvme0n1 but it says COMMAND NOT FOUND. Should I try anything else?
